# mysql and PHP to assign points to users from a pool of points and ranked

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

This is a bit of a complex one that I have been trying to solve as much as possible with only a query but I have been failing to do so accurately. I have a semi solution in PHP but this sometimes fails.

First to explain the situation, I am building out a sort of MVP system. Whereby only the top 3 placed players receive points, that is fine, however I run into issues when there is a draw in the voting.

The point spread would be

```
1st place 3 points
2nd place 2 points
3rd place 1 point
```

For a total pool of 5 points. At the moment I have a recursive function in php which mostly works, it takes the total points remaining and divides it among the remaining placements, I am just wondering if this could be solved in a single query.

So what you may get is

```
Player 1 = 10 votes
players 2 = 9 votes 
player 3 = 9 votes.
```

So here the points spread should be

```
Player 1 = 3 points
Player 2 = 1.5 points
player 3 = 1.5 points (remaining points in pool divided by 2 players)
```

And again the same applies no matter where that match up lies

So again if you had

```
player 1 = 10 votes
player 2 = 10 votes
player 3 = 9 votes
Player 4 = 9 votes
```

In the circumstances above the point spread would be

```
Player 1 & Player 2 = 2.5 points
Player 3 & Player 4 = 0.5 points
```

So I believe I can do this with a recursive php function which just does a calculation of something like remaining_points / players_left

This for some reason occasionally fails and ultimately I would like to be able to do this from a single query and not have to worry about pumping it through PHP functions.

Or any other thoughts on how to achieve this?

Cheers
Dan

- EDIT 1: For disclosure this is a function I wrote a long time ago in PHP that mostly worked, but I think is probably too specific for scope of stackoverflow. It may help paint the picture though

  ```
  function stpoty_update_standings($round, $season)   {
  global $db;

  //Do the calculation to update the standings. We could probably do this without extra storage but will leave it as is for now.
  $player_points = $db->write_query("Select vote, sum(points) as points from ".TABLE_PREFIX."stpoty_votes where round_id=".intval($round)." group by vote order by points DESC");
  $gpoints=3;

  while($pps=$db->fetch_array($player_points))    {

      $users_run = explode(",", $user_collection);

      if(in_array($pps["vote"], $users_run)==false)   {

          if($gpoints!='0')   {
              //lets check how many people have these points
              $equal_vote = $db->write_query("Select count(vote) from ".TABLE_PREFIX."stpoty_votes where round_id=".intval($round)." group by vote HAVING sum(points)=".$pps["points"]." order by points DESC LIMIT 1");
              $equal_votes = $db->num_rows($equal_vote);
              //now we have a count we can do what we need to do
              if($equal_votes==1) {
                  //We have one user on this score so we can just update their record, we need to check if they exist to perform the right action
                  $exists = $db->write_query( "SELECT points FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."stpoty_standings where comp=".intval($season)." and player=".intval($pps["vote"]));
                  $exists = $db->fetch_field($exists, "points");
                  if(!empty($exists)) {
                      stpoty_update_standings_update($pps["vote"], $gpoints, $exists, $season);
                  }   else    {
                      stpoty_update_standings_insert($pps["vote"], $gpoints, $season);
                  }
                  $gpoints = --$gpoints;
              } else if ($equal_votes>=2) {

                  //if we have two or more points we need to divide remaining points between them, and null out of the loop
                  if($gpoints=='3') {

                          //work out the division of points
                      if($equal_votes==2) {
                          $apoints = "2.5";
                          $gpoints = "1";
                      }   else if ($equal_votes>=3) {
                          $apoints = 5 / $equal_votes;
                          $gpoints = 0;
                      }
                  }   else if ($gpoints=='2') {
                      //work out the division of points
                      $apoints = 3 / $equal_votes;
                      $gpoints = 0;
                  }   else if ($gpoints=='1') {
                      $apoints = 1 / $equal_votes;
                      $gpoints = 0;
                  }
                  $comma = "";    
                  $players_on_points = $db->write_query("Select vote, sum(points) from ".TABLE_PREFIX."stpoty_votes where round_id=".intval($round)." group by vote Having sum(points)=".$pps["points"]." order by points DESC");

                  while($pop=$db->fetch_array($players_on_points))    {

                      $exist = $db->write_query( "SELECT points FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."stpoty_standings where comp=".intval($season)." and player=".intval($pop["vote"]));
                      $exists = $db->fetch_field($exist, "points");
                      $user_collection .= $comma.$pop["vote"];
                      if(!empty($exists)) {

                          stpoty_update_standings_update($pop["vote"], $apoints, $exists, $season);
                      }   else    {

                          stpoty_update_standings_insert($pop["vote"], $apoints, $season);
                      }
                      $comma = ",";
                  }

              }
          }
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: In the last scenario should the 6 points not be split between 1&2 or must there always be a 3rd & 4th place when this is applicaple?

Comment: There should always be 3 players awarded MVP. So if there are 2 players in 1st rank, then they get a split of points from 1st and 2nd position. 

Leaving someone to come 3rd, in this case two people. Whilst this could potentially leave the people coming first with less points than 3rd sobeit.

Potentially and in the past I have seen ties at all levels including 5 or more players who came 3rd.